# "Socket Hang Up" Error not being caught on node.js with rxjs

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I'm getting random `Socket Hang Up` errors on my node app. My app posts over 1,000 images to a server for processing and it happens at random points so it's very difficult to reproduce. Annoyingly it usually happens just when you think it's not going to happen!

I'm using RXJS and I have created a wrapper library for the node http functions here:

https://github.com/Roaders/rx-http-ts

The code that does the requests is:

```
 export function makeHttpRequest(options: http.RequestOptions, data?: any): Rx.Observable<string>{

  return Rx.Observable.defer(() => {
    const request = options.protocol === HTTPS ? https.request(options) : http.request(options) ;

    const errorObservable = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(<any>request, "error")
        .flatMap(error => {
            return Rx.Observable.throw(error);
        });

    const responseObservable = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(<any>request, "response");

    if(data){
        request.write(data);
    }

    request.end();

    return responseObservable.merge(errorObservable)
        .take(1);
    })
    .flatMap( response => RxNode.fromReadableStream(<any>response))
    .toArray()
    .map(function(allData){
        return allData.join("");
    });
}
```

I don't understand how I can be getting that error and that it's not being caught. I'm listening for the error events from the request object and errors on the stream should be handled by `RxNode.fromReadableStream`

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: When you later subscribe to the Observable returned from `makeHttpRequest()` do you have also the error callback? Can you have a look to the stack trace where is the error first thrown?

Comment: I have been logging the error but I haven't been able to get a stack trace. As it can be about an hour before this happens it's not easy to replicate :-(